# Facebook Graph api is way too slow

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Hello I'm new to android and facebook graph api programming just about a week. I want to make an app showing videos feed uploaded by public page.
i'm using Facebook graph api SDK for android to request information for videos list of a public page but it gets error many time

```
{HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: 1, errorType: null, errorMessage: An unknown error occurred}
```

sometime it works fine in a second! sometime it takes 20000+ ms 
, this problem are both happened on Graph Api Explorer and my android studio

this parameter that I've requested are

```
("fields", "title,likes.limit(0).summary(true),source,picture,description,thumbnails");
```

but when i requested to information for specified video it response in a sec.

Anyone could help? Is there other way to make it faster. Thank you so much.

Ps.This is my first time here after a long long time being a reader

english isn't my native. sorry if I wrote something wrong.

**UPDATE**

For anyone who's facing this problem.
I found the problems was that if the page we are getting data from have lots of videos it will lead to take a long time or false to get it

the solution is you don't need get the videos information , call feeds data instead